# When using `TextVectorization` to tokenize strings, the input rank must be 1 or the last shape dimension must be 1. Received:

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, recommendation-engine

I am trying to replicate listwise loss for deep ranking model, basically I have trying to combine below two documentations from tensorflow.org.

1. https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/listwise_ranking
2. https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/deep_recommenders

Below are the detailed code, but this is giving error as  `` When using `TextVectorization` to tokenize strings, the input rank must be 1 or the last shape dimension must be 1. Received: inputs.shape=(None, 5) with rank=2 ``

How can I flatten the tensor data so `TextVectorization` can work? I have tried using tf.flatten() but no sucees.

```
!pip install -q tensorflow-recommenders
!pip install -q --upgrade tensorflow-datasets
!pip install -q tensorflow-ranking

import pprint

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

import tensorflow_ranking as tfr
import tensorflow_recommenders as tfrs
from typing import Dict, Text
import os
import tempfile

ratings = tfds.load("movielens/100k-ratings", split="train")
movies = tfds.load("movielens/100k-movies", split="train")

ratings = ratings.map(lambda x: {
    "movie_title": x["movie_title"],
    "user_id": x["user_id"],
    "user_rating": x["user_rating"],
    # "timestamp": x["timestamp"],
})
movies = movies.map(lambda x: x["movie_title"])

unique_movie_titles = np.unique(np.concatenate(list(movies.batch(1000))))
unique_user_ids = np.unique(np.concatenate(list(ratings.batch(1_000).map(
    lambda x: x["user_id"]))))

tf.random.set_seed(42)

# Split between train and tests sets, as before.
shuffled = ratings.shuffle(100_000, seed=42, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

train = shuffled.take(80_000)
test = shuffled.skip(80_000).take(20_000)

# We sample 50 lists for each user for the training data. For each list we
# sample 5 movies from the movies the user rated.
train = tfrs.examples.movielens.sample_listwise(
    train,
    num_list_per_user=50,
    num_examples_per_list=5,
    seed=42
)
test = tfrs.examples.movielens.sample_listwise(
    test,
    num_list_per_user=1,
    num_examples_per_list=5,
    seed=42
)

for example in train.take(1):
  pprint.pprint(example)

class UserModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.user_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
            vocabulary=unique_user_ids, mask_token=None),
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_user_ids) + 1, 32),
    ])
    # self.timestamp_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
    #     tf.keras.layers.Discretization(timestamp_buckets.tolist()),
    #     tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(timestamp_buckets) + 1, 32),
    # ])
    # self.normalized_timestamp = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(
    #     axis=None
    # )

    # self.normalized_timestamp.adapt(timestamps)

  def call(self, inputs):
    # Take the input dictionary, pass it through each input layer,
    # and concatenate the result.
    # return tf.concat([
    #     self.user_embedding(inputs["user_id"]),
    #     self.timestamp_embedding(inputs["timestamp"]),
    #     tf.reshape(self.normalized_timestamp(inputs["timestamp"]), (-1, 1)),
    # ], axis=1)
    return self.user_embedding(inputs["user_id"])


class QueryModel(tf.keras.Model):
  """Model for encoding user queries."""

  def __init__(self, layer_sizes):
    """Model for encoding user queries.

    Args:
      layer_sizes:
        A list of integers where the i-th entry represents the number of units
        the i-th layer contains.
    """
    super().__init__()

    # We first use the user model for generating embeddings.
    self.embedding_model = UserModel()

    # Then construct the layers.
    self.dense_layers = tf.keras.Sequential()

    # Use the ReLU activation for all but the last layer.
    for layer_size in layer_sizes[:-1]:
      self.dense_layers.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(layer_size, activation="relu"))

    # No activation for the last layer.
    for layer_size in layer_sizes[-1:]:
      self.dense_layers.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(layer_size))

  def call(self, inputs):
    feature_embedding = self.embedding_model(inputs)
    return self.dense_layers(feature_embedding)


class MovieModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    max_tokens = 10_000

    self.title_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
          vocabulary=unique_movie_titles,mask_token=None),
      tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_movie_titles) + 1, 32)
    ])

    self.title_vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
        max_tokens=max_tokens)

    self.title_text_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
      self.title_vectorizer,
      tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_tokens, 32, mask_zero=True),
      tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    ])

    self.title_vectorizer.adapt(movies)

  def call(self, titles):
    return tf.concat([
        self.title_embedding(titles),
        self.title_text_embedding(titles),
    ], axis=1)


class CandidateModel(tf.keras.Model):
  """Model for encoding movies."""

  def __init__(self, layer_sizes):
    """Model for encoding movies.

    Args:
      layer_sizes:
        A list of integers where the i-th entry represents the number of units
        the i-th layer contains.
    """
    super().__init__()

    self.embedding_model = MovieModel()

    # Then construct the layers.
    self.dense_layers = tf.keras.Sequential()

    # Use the ReLU activation for all but the last layer.
    for layer_size in layer_sizes[:-1]:
      self.dense_layers.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(layer_size, activation="relu"))

    # No activation for the last layer.
    for layer_size in layer_sizes[-1:]:
      self.dense_layers.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(layer_size))

  def call(self, inputs):
    feature_embedding = self.embedding_model(inputs)
    return self.dense_layers(feature_embedding)


class MovielensModel(tfrs.models.Model):

  def __init__(self, layer_sizes):
    super().__init__()
    self.query_model = QueryModel(layer_sizes)
    self.candidate_model = CandidateModel(layer_sizes)
    self.rating_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    ])
    self.rating_task: tf.keras.layers.Layer = tfrs.tasks.Ranking(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()],
    )

  def call(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor]) -> tf.Tensor:
    # We pick out the user features and pass them into the user model.
    query_embeddings = self.query_model({
        "user_id": features["user_id"],
        # "timestamp": features["timestamp"],
    })
    movie_embeddings = self.candidate_model(features["movie_title"])

    return (
        user_embeddings,
        movie_embeddings,
        # We apply the multi-layered rating model to a concatentation of
        # user and movie embeddings.
        self.rating_model(
            tf.concat([user_embeddings, movie_embeddings], axis=1)
        ),
    )
  
  def compute_loss(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor], training=False) -> tf.Tensor:
    # We only pass the user id and timestamp features into the query model. This
    # is to ensure that the training inputs would have the same keys as the
    # query inputs. Otherwise the discrepancy in input structure would cause an
    # error when loading the query model after saving it.
    ratings = features.pop("user_rating")

    user_embeddings, movie_embeddings, rating_predictions = self(features)

    rating_loss = self.rating_task(
        labels=ratings,
        predictions=rating_predictions,
    )
    retrieval_loss = self.retrieval_task(user_embeddings, movie_embeddings)

    return (retrieval_loss)

model = MovielensModel(layer_sizes=[32])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(0.1))


cached_train = train.shuffle(100_000).batch(8192).cache()
cached_test = test.batch(4096).cache()


model.fit(cached_train, epochs=3)
metrics = model.evaluate(cached_test, return_dict=True)

print(f"Retrieval top-100 accuracy: {metrics['factorized_top_k/top_100_categorical_accuracy']:.3f}.")
print(f"Ranking RMSE: {metrics['root_mean_squared_error']:.3f}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to reshape input for `TextVectorization` such that last shape dimension is always 1, but doing so resultanted in other error due to mismatch of shape, below is the detailed code on how all error were rectified.

````
!pip install -q tensorflow-recommenders
!pip install -q --upgrade tensorflow-datasets
!pip install -q tensorflow-ranking

import pprint
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow_ranking as tfr
import tensorflow_recommenders as tfrs
from typing import Dict, Text
import os
import tempfile

%load_ext tensorboard


class UserModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.user_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
            vocabulary=unique_user_ids, mask_token=None),
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_user_ids) + 1, 32),
    ])


  def call(self, inputs):
    return self.user_embedding(inputs["user_id"])



class QueryModel(tf.keras.Model):
  """Model for encoding user queries."""

  def __init__(self, layer_sizes):
    """Model for encoding user queries.

    Args:
      layer_sizes:
        A list of integers where the i-th entry represents the number of units
        the i-th layer contains.
    """
    super().__init__()

    # We first use the user model for generating embeddings.
    self.embedding_model = UserModel()

    # Then construct the layers.
    self.dense_layers = tf.keras.Sequential()
    # self.dense_layers.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(32,))) ##Input 0 of layer "dense_10" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (32,)


    # Use the ReLU activation for all but the last layer.
    for layer_size in layer_sizes[:-1]:
      self.dense_layers.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(layer_size, activation="relu"))

    # No activation for the last layer.
    for layer_size in layer_sizes[-1:]:
      self.dense_layers.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(layer_size))

  def call(self, inputs):
    feature_embedding = self.embedding_model(inputs)
    return self.dense_layers(feature_embedding)





class MovieModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    max_tokens = 10_000_00

    self.title_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
          vocabulary=unique_movie_titles,mask_token=None),
      tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_movie_titles) + 1, 32)
    ])

    self.title_vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
        max_tokens=max_tokens,output_sequence_length = 4)

    self.title_text_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
      self.title_vectorizer,
      tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_tokens, 32, mask_zero=True),
    ])
    self.title_vectorizer.adapt(movies)

  def call(self, titles, pool_size):
    avg_layer = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=pool_size,strides=1,padding='valid',)
    len_titles=tf.shape(titles)[0]
    # return avg_layer(self.title_text_embedding(titles))
    return tf.concat([
        self.title_embedding(tf.reshape(titles,[len_titles,5,1])),
        avg_layer(self.title_text_embedding(tf.reshape(titles,[len_titles,5,1]))),
    ], axis=3)




class CandidateModel(tf.keras.Model):
  """Model for encoding movies."""

  def __init__(self, layer_sizes):
    """Model for encoding movies.

    Args:
      layer_sizes:
        A list of integers where the i-th entry represents the number of units
        the i-th layer contains.
    """
    super().__init__()

    self.embedding_model = MovieModel()

    # Then construct the layers.
    self.dense_layers = tf.keras.Sequential()

    # Use the ReLU activation for all but the last layer.
    for layer_size in layer_sizes[:-1]:
      self.dense_layers.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(layer_size, activation="relu"))

    # No activation for the last layer.
    for layer_size in layer_sizes[-1:]:
      self.dense_layers.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(layer_size))

  def call(self, inputs,pool_size):
    feature_embedding = self.embedding_model(inputs,pool_size)
    return self.dense_layers(feature_embedding)






class MovielensModel(tfrs.models.Model):

  def __init__(self, layer_sizes):
    super().__init__()
    self.query_model = QueryModel(layer_sizes)
    self.candidate_model = CandidateModel(layer_sizes)
    self.rating_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    ])
    # self.rating_task: tf.keras.layers.Layer = tfrs.tasks.Ranking(
    #     loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
    #     metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()],
    # )
    self.rating_task: tf.keras.layers.Layer = tfrs.tasks.Ranking(
        loss=tfr.keras.losses.ListMLELoss(),
        metrics=[tfr.keras.metrics.NDCGMetric(name="ndcg_metric"),
                 tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()],
    )

  def call(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor]) -> tf.Tensor:
    # We pick out the user features and pass them into the user model.
    # print(len(features["movie_title"]))
    # for x in features["movie_title"]:
    #   print(x)
    self.query_embeddings = self.query_model({
        "user_id": features["user_id"],
        # "timestamp": features["timestamp"],
    })
    self.movie_embeddings = self.candidate_model(features["movie_title"],pool_size=(1,4))

    list_length = features["movie_title"].shape[1]
    self.query_embeddings_repeated = tf.repeat(
        tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(self.query_embeddings, 1), 1), [list_length], axis=1)
    self.embd_concat=tf.concat([self.query_embeddings_repeated, self.movie_embeddings], 3)
    return (
        self.query_embeddings,
        self.movie_embeddings,
        # We apply the multi-layered rating model to a concatentation of
        # user and movie embeddings.
        self.rating_model(
            self.embd_concat
        ),
    )
  
  def compute_loss(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor], training=False) -> tf.Tensor:
    # We only pass the user id and timestamp features into the query model. This
    # is to ensure that the training inputs would have the same keys as the
    # query inputs. Otherwise the discrepancy in input structure would cause an
    # error when loading the query model after saving it.
    ratings = features.pop("user_rating")

    user_embeddings, movie_embeddings, rating_predictions = self(features)
    # print('4',ratings.shape)
    # tf.print('5',rating_predictions.shape)

    #       return backend.mean(tf.math.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true), axis=-1)
    # Node: 'ranking_1/mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference'
    # Incompatible shapes: [8192,5] vs. [8192,5,2,1]

    rating_loss = self.rating_task(
        labels=ratings,
        predictions=tf.squeeze(tf.squeeze(rating_predictions, axis=-1), axis=-1), ## when loss used in MLE then rating_prediction must be of rank 2 this is mandatory hence we use squeez here.
    )
    # retrieval_loss = self.retrieval_task(user_embeddings, movie_embeddings)

    return (rating_loss)






model = MovielensModel(layer_sizes=[32])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(0.1))


cached_train = train.shuffle(100_000).batch(1000).cache()
cached_test = test.batch(4096).cache()


log_dir = "./" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
model_hist = model.fit(cached_train, epochs=10)
metrics = model.evaluate(cached_test, return_dict=True)

print(f"Ranking RMSE: {metrics['root_mean_squared_error']:.3f}.")



for x in train.take(1):
  print(x)
  predicted_rating = model.predict({
                  "user_id": np.array([x['user_id'].numpy().decode('utf-8')]),
                  "movie_title": np.array([list(map(lambda y: y.decode('utf-8'),x['movie_title'].numpy()))]),
              # "user_rating" : np.array([list(x['user_rating'].numpy())]) ### THIS WORKS
              "user_rating" : np.array([x['user_rating'].numpy()]) ### THIS ALSO WORKS WE HAVE REMOVED "list" function
          })



predicted_rating[2]



%tensorboard --logdir .

model.summary()

model.candidate_model.summary()

```
````